# Zend Framework 2 SessionManager, SessionArrayStorage and 'Expire' functionality

Tags: php, zend-framework2

My question is about Expire metadata key which is use by Zend 2 SessionStorage for Containers.

Is there any function which take care about clearing Containers which are expired or i should just implement one? I know it will be easy to do, I just want to know if I miss something.

To clarify, we have sec_token from Csrf validator which is stored in session in container. It has Expire timestamp im metedata key and we have this container with csrf hash.

[image: Session]

After some digging I couldn't find any build in function or behavior which will automatically clear my session storage from expired containers. We have to implement this behavior or I`m missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The code you are looking for located in Zend\Session\AbstractContainer.php
in method expireByExpiryTime. It is called in expireKeys () from the same file and clears any expired keys every time you try to access it.

Comment: I found that too, but i dont like "every time you try to access it" part. I think it would be better if it could be cleared automatically from session storage. Mainly because after some time of using particular storage we will have lots of data in it. Its nice that zend will know which one is expired just of metadata key but what if i just need container once and will not use it anymore? It will stay in storage as long as session is not cleared for the user? What if someone is logged in with remember me option then this expired container will be still in session storage. Is that ok?

Comment: The fact that some stale data is in the storage doesn't hurt, since you don't access it anyway. And when you do it disappears. I don't see any problem with this.

Comment: Lets consider my example. I have form with Csrf token. Now lets say someone opens 5 times same form in different window each. Every time form  has another csrf hash right. I store it in session for validation. In zend I added salt for Csrf container name, which is random generated because if its not, another same form which will be open, will override hash from last same form, now i have Session storage with 5 different Containers which have hashes for form which is opened 5 times. My session storage will grow just because of this behavior? Maybe i miss something and this is fine?

Comment: It will only store the csrf token for the last form opened. The CSRF tokens for the previous 4 forms will be removed and if the user attempted to submit any of those forms it would be rejected due to invalid CSRF token.

Comment: @Tomdarkness You are absolutely right. I wanted to find out on my own how it works here and i found prepare function in Form/Elements/Csrf which every time generates new token. Sometimes i just want to know what exactly happens under the table. Tanks for your answers ;)